# How to put controls in the footer of the gridview(not belongs to specific column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

Q:

How to put a table from two columns and one row in the footer of the gridview. the footer  doesn't belong to any column .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the footer manually from codebehind in [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) of the GridView.

For example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) {
        var grid = (GridView)sender;
        Label lbl1 = new Label();
        Label lbl2 = new Label();
        TableCell footerCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        TableRow footerRow = new TableRow();
        Table footerTable = new Table();
        e.Row.Cells.Clear();
        footerCell.Controls.Add(footerTable);
        footerTable.Rows.Add(footerRow);
        lbl1.ID = "lbl1";
        lbl2.ID = "lbl2";
        cell1.Controls.Add(lbl1);
        cell2.Controls.Add(lbl2);
        footerRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
        footerRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
        e.Row.Cells.Add(footerCell);
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) {
        DataRow row = getFooterSource().Rows[0];
        var lbl1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl1");
        var lbl2 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl2");
        lbl1.Text = row["Col1"];
        lbl2.Text = row["Col2"];
        e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = ((DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource).Columns.Count;
    }
}

//get some mock-data
private DataTable getFooterSource()
{
    DataTable tblFooter = new DataTable("Footer");
    tblFooter.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
    tblFooter.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
    var footerRow = tblFooter.NewRow();
    footerRow(0) = "first column's value";
    footerRow(1) = "second column's value";
    tblFooter.Rows.Add(footerRow);
    return tblFooter;
}
```